# Parsing MUI V5 DatePicker dateObject to date

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form, zod

I would like to validate my DatePicker field input from MUI V5 with Zod and React Hook Form.

```js
<Controller
  name = {id}
  control = {control}
  defaultValue = {defaultValue}
  render = {({field: {ref,...field}}) => ( 
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter = {AdapterDayjs}>
        <DatePicker 
          label = {label}
          value = {field.value}
          onChange = {(id) => field.onChange(id)}
          maxDate = {maxDate && maxDate}
          minDate = {minDate && minDate}
          renderInput = {(params) => ( 
            <TextField 
              inputRef = {ref}
              required = {required}
              { ...params}
              fullWidth size = "small"
              error = {!!errors[id]}
              helperText = {errors[id]?.message?.toString()}
              { ...field}
            />
          )}
        /> 
      </LocalizationProvider>
    )
 />
```

My sample validation schema

```js
export const personalDataSchema = z.object({
  birthDate: z
    .date({
      errorMap: (issue, _ctx) => {
        switch (issue.code) {
          case "invalid_type":
            return { message: "Enter a valid birth date!" };
          case "invalid_enum_value":
            return { message: "Enter a valid birth date!" };
          default:
            return { message: "Enter a valid birth date!" };
        }
      },
    })
    .max(birthDateMin, "Employee must be older than 18 years!"),
});
```

The validation always fails because the value is an object, not a date.
How do I get the date picker field to return a date type?